# ios present view controller immediately after dismissing a previous one

Tags: ios, object, presentviewcontroller

In my ios app lets say I have three `ViewControllers`: `A`, `B`, and `C`.

From `A` I present `B` and assign `A` as a delegate. After an action is done on `B` I want to then dismiss `B` and present `C` from `A`. However, I want to do this without `A` showing up on the screen at all. This is my code right now, inside class `A`:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    B *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"B-identifier"];
    vc.delegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:NO completion:^{}];

}
```

Then this is the delegate function inside `A` that `B` calls when the action is performed:

```
- (void) actionPerformed
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    C *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"C"];
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:NO completion:nil];
}];
```

However this causes C to show up for a bit (after calling dismiss) even though I put the presenting code in the completion handler of the dismissal. What can I do to avoid that?

Comment: Bro the best way to do this according to me will be by adding your B and C as child view controller of A not by presenting them modally. If you want I can give you code.

Comment: I am using this mechanism to handle login -- so A is the root view controller which checks if a user is logged in. If not, it displays the login view (view controller B). Once a user logs in, It then will show C.

Comment: @iDeveloper show ur code and let understand what do u mean by dealing with childviewcontrollers and how u do that without showing A viewcontroller

Comment: @NarasimhaiahKolli you can transit between two childViewController by using [self transitionFromViewController: toViewController: duration: options: animations: completion:] method in your parent class. I hope you got me bro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using it for login approach then you should try a different approach. I mean if A is your rootViewController(make it as login view controller) which check if user has a session or not. suppose user has a session then make your C viewController as rootViewController using `[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window]setRootViewController:]` and if he does not has a session show him the same page (A viewController) there is no need of B. Just try it may be it will improve your app performance.

Comment: due to legacy code its easier for me to still have three view controllers. But i modified the action code to set C as the root view and this ensures theres is no delay

Answer (score -1):

```
You can manage this by timeinterval
like This way
```

you can first dissmiss the view 
    [self dismiss];

```
-(void)dismiss
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    [self performSelector:@selector(present) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0];
}
-(void)present
{
    C *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"C"];
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:NO completion:nil];
}
```