# Initial ViewController changes as per Login in storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, transition

In my project initial entry point in storyboard is **LoginViewController**. If user login to app I always want to show main `ViewController` of app by escaping **LoginViewCntyroller**, I did that following code in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method.

```
if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:IS_SIGNIN_CHECK])
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        [self showMainScreen];
    });

-(void) showMainScreen
{
   UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
   SWRevealViewController  *viewController = (SWRevealViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainScreenViewID"];
   [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
   [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:viewController
                                             animated:NO
                                           completion:nil];
}
```

It's working fine. But problem is when it goes to **MainViewController**, it goes to **LoginViewController** for few seconds and then shows **MainViewController**. How to avoid that transition form **LoginViewController** to **MainViewController**?

Answer (score 1):

you are presenting your main screen through the `LoginViewController`. Means first the `LoginViewController view` will load and display to user and then it will redirect to `main screen` there is no way to avoid it using this scheme.

But you can avoid it by setting your `main screen` as `rootViewController` of main window and it will work fine

```
if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:IS_SIGNIN_CHECK])
    [self showMainScreen];


-(void) showMainScreen
{
   UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
   SWRevealViewController  *viewController = (SWRevealViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainScreenViewID"];
   self.window.rootViewController = viewController;
}
```

Comment: I did this but still it showed me LoginViewController few seconds and then shows MainViewController.

Comment: I did this also getting this Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <LoginViewController: 0x7fc4ead6f0d0>. and work like previously.

Comment: I think Its taking storyboard entry point anyhow and then execute code. So  it goes to LoginViewController then execute code logic and shows MainViewController.

Comment: @iOS06 This is not possible if you are using above mentioned code in my answer. Because you are directly setting the viewController as your rootViewController without going through the login page. Please recheck your code. check out my another answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26381393/ios-present-view-controller-immediately-after-dismissing-a-previous-one/26381831#26381831